# Convert Windows 7 Virtual PC to Windows 8 Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, virtualization, windows-8

My business develops software, and as such I have setup Virtual PC servers on my Windows 7 work station.  I've now upgraded to Windows 8, and didn't realize VPC was replaced with Hyper-V.  Is there a way to get my existing virtual PCs running under Hyper V?  I still have access to another Windows 7 machine if I need to use that for some of the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2012/01/18/can-you-move-a-virtual-machine-from-virtualpc-to-hyper-v.aspx) outlines the process pretty well.

You basically just uninstall the VPC components, move the VHD and attach it to a new Hyper-V guest, boot it up and install the Hyper-V integration components.

Comment: Is it possible to run the virtual machine without uninstalling VPC components first?  Or will that cause problems with Hyper-V?  Trying to figure out if this is a one or two workstation process.

Comment: That article says to uninstall them first. I've never tried the other way.

Comment: I tried it without uninstalling first, and it seemed to work.  Just cancel all the Found New Hardware wizards (this was Win2k3), uninstall the VPC integration components.  It will reboot, then use Hyper V to insert the HV integration components.